# Switch from UIViewController to a TabBarController

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, switch-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Switching from UIViewController to UITabBarController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13830375/switching-from-uiviewcontroller-to-uitabbarcontroller)

Im trying to show a UIViewController for 2 seconds before the UITabBarController, i know i have to make it fromm my appdelegate. Ive tried by first assigning my self.window.rootviewcontroller to my UIViewController and with a scheduled timer after 2 seconds reassigning my self.window.rootviewcontroller to my UITabViewController.

The problem is that when i test it, my viewcontroller shows up, but after the 2 seconds the app crashes.

This is my LaMetro_88AppDelegate.h

```
@interface LaMetro_88AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate>
{
    UIView *startupView;
    NSTimer *timer;

    UIViewController *LoadingViewController;
    UITabBarController *tabBarController;
}

-(void)changeView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIViewController *LoadingViewController;

@end
```

This is my LaMetro_88AppDelegate.m

```
@implementation LaMetro_88AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize tabBarController = _tabBarController;
@synthesize LoadingViewController = _LoadingViewController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
     self.window.rootViewController = self.LoadingViewController;

    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(changeView:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

-(void)changeView
{

    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;  

}
```

Comment: Not just a possible duplicate, it's exactly the same question.

Comment: sorry i thought it didnt published... im going to delete this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `changeView` method doesn't take a parameter, it's method signature doesn't include a colon. Change your selector to `changeView` without the colon:

```
@selector(changeView)
```

Comment: Yes that made the difference... Im self teaching me so I make this noob mistakes :) thanks for ur time

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(changeView:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

To this:

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(changeView) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

Comment: I will give it a try right now.